# Internal Rpc error when i call claim function on this my contract and i got payload error if use edge browsser instead of chrome to perform same task

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask, rpc, airdrop

My js code

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () => {
  let web3;
  let accounts;

  const initWeb3 = async () => {
    try {
      // Use the appropriate provider URL for the BSC network
      web3 = new Web3("https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545/");

      web3.setProvider(window.ethereum);
      // Request account access
      accounts = await window.ethereum.request({
        method: "eth_requestAccounts",
      });
      updateConnectButtonText(); // Update button text on wallet connect
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error initializing Web3:", error);
    }
  };
```

My contracts link https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x3f12b2bea6990e4cae2f0b5481dada5ca88677d0

Some one should please help me, increased gas massively still  no head way